# FullCalander 5 add event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm building a CRM and trying to make a button outside the calendar div and if I press the button, it should be creating an event on the and it's not working. Could someone please point me out what I'm doing wrong?

This is what I tried:

```
  $(document).on("click", "#testbtn", function(){
    var calendarEl = $("#calendar");
    calendarEl.addEvent({events: [
      {
        title: 'Second Event',
        start: '2020-08-08T12:30:00',
        end: '2020-08-08T13:30:00'
      }
    ]});
  });
```

This is my whole script:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src='../lib/main.js'></script>
<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    <!-- all the options here -->
    calendar.render();
  });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="testbtn">Add lunch time</button>
  <div id='calendar-container'>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </div>
<script src="/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var options = {  /*Add options here*/};
  var calendarEl = $("#calendar");
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, options);

  $(document).on("click", "#testbtn", function(){
    calendar.addEvent({
      title: 'Lunch',
      start: '2020-08-08T12:30:00',
      end: '2020-08-08T13:30:00'
    });
    calendar.render();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't do `new FullCalendar.Calendar` twice.  All the code can live in one `<script>` tag (and in actual use, should be in a .js file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. `calendarEl` is a DOM element.  It won't have a `.addEvent` property (at least not the FullCalendar one.)
2. The argument for [`addEvent`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent) is a single [Event object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object), not an object with a key `events` and an array of events as a value.

The [`addEvent` demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent-demo) may be helpful for you.

You need to pass the `FullCalendar.Calendar` instance, which you create with the `new` keyword, to the event handling function.

```js
  var calendarEl = $("#calendar").get(0);
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
  }); 
  calendar.render();
  $("#testbtn").on("click", function(){
    calendar.addEvent({
        title: 'Second Event',
        start: '2020-08-08T12:30:00',
        end: '2020-08-08T13:30:00'
      });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, still no go. I got

```
<button id="testbtn">Add lunch time</button>
  <div id='calendar-container'>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </div>
<script src="/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var options = {  /*Add options here*/};
  var calendarEl = $("#calendar");
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, options);

  $(document).on("click", "#testbtn", function(){
    calendar.addEvent({
      title: 'Lunch',
      start: '2020-08-08T12:30:00',
      end: '2020-08-08T13:30:00'
    });
    calendar.render();
  });
</script>

Comment: @CameronW - I didn't fully test with jQuery.  I updated my post to show a minimal working example.

Comment: We are getting somewhere. If I insert "
    calendar.render();" after the add event function, it clears my other events and shows the third event.

Comment: @CameronW - yep, mea culpa - I forget the calendar.render.  Again, this is all shown in the official [demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent-demo), click "Edit in CodePen" to see details.  I have updated my answer.  If I make the event that is added variable, it creates a new event for each click.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to post this after where you load the jquery script. This has already got events loaded. We are just adding an event.

Body

```
<body>
<button id="testbtn">Add lunch time</button>
  <div id='calendar-container'>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </div>
<script src="/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Then call the full calendar plugin

```
<script>
  var calendarEl = $("#calendar").get(0);
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    /*options...*/
    events:
            [
              {
                id: 1,
                title: 'First Event',
                start: '2020-08-08T10:30:00',
                end: '2020-08-08T11:30:00',
                extendedProps: {
                  description: 'Test 1'
                },
                color: '#336e03'
              },

              {
                id: 2,
                title: 'Second Event',
                start: '2020-08-08T15:30:00',
                end: '2020-08-08T16:30:00',
                extendedProps: {
                  description: 'Test 2'
                },
              }
            ]

  });

  calendar.render();
/*this is the action when the button is pressed*/
  $("#testbtn").on("click", function(){
    calendar.addEvent({
      title: 'Third Event',
      start: '2020-08-08T12:30:00',
      end: '2020-08-08T13:30:00'
    });
  });
</script>
```